# The claim process removes the secretKey, how to restore it if I do a reclaim?

Tags: thingsboard

We're using the thingsboard CE for a smarthome application. We're considering the claim process to let the user to add a new device. We developed a proof of concept following the process described in here: https://thingsboard.io/docs/user-guide/claiming-devices/

Now we're considering the use case of removing the device to let another user to add it (like selling the device to another person), but when we reclaim the device (according to "Device Reclaiming API Request") the device doesn't have the secretKey, so, we cannot let another user claim the device.

Are we missing something? Is there another way to do what we want?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest handling it in the rule chain. One solution would be to have a button on a management dashboard. Clicking the button sets a "reclaim flag" to true (or you can do it direct from default attribute edit window). The rule chain receives this action, notices the flag and does the following:

1. Adds a secretKey attribute
2. Re-enables device claiming (I think once a device is claimed it can't be reclaimed again by default)
3. Flips the "reclaim flag" back to false
4. Changes the "owner" of the device back to the tenant (optional but I recommend it).

Alternatively, if you didn't want to deal with the flag bit, you could have the rule chain listen for any time an device has it's owner changed to the tenant. Might be a little less secure though.

Comment: Jackson, seems a good idea, but where do you obtain the new secretKey, because the first one is stored in the device during the manufacturing process and then stored in TB; so, if I create in TB a new secretKey should be stored in the device too.

Comment: The secretKey can be whatever you want. Personally I don't use a secretKey for my device claiming. I just assume that if the user knows the `deviceName` (I use IMEI for this) then they should be able to claim the device. Is it 100% necessary for the secretKey stored on the device to match the one on TB? If so, could you elaborate why?